# Execute GET request after logging in command line

Tags: http, unix, curl, wget

I wish execute a GET request on a specific url, but before be able to do that, I have to establish a connection.
Logically, I have to be connected to the website.

I tried with curl and wget, something like that :

`curl -d server_name=www.starsquest.co.uk&uni=1&username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&x=0&y=0" --dump-header headers http://s2.starsquest.co.uk/?page=login`

The connection seems work, I get something like :

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.36-0+deb7u3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Set-Cookie: StarsQuest=1asb9t24g9l26lpdu207h8rms2; expires=Sun, 24-Jul-2016 07:20:17 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://s2.starsquest.co.uk/game.php?mode=login
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 07:20:17 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.31
```

The next request is :

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://s2.starsquest.co.uk/game.php?page=showfleets&ajax=1
```

But how to use the pre established connection ? Is it possible ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use `cookie-jar` option in both requests:

```
curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt -d "server_name=www.starsquest.co.uk&uni=1&username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&x=0&y=0" --dump-header headers "http://s2.starsquest.co.uk/?page=login"

curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET "http://s2.starsquest.co.uk/game.php?page=showfleets&ajax=1"
```

This will read cookies from given file before making a request and store the new ones in it after done, so it will allow you to store the session data.

Comment: Ok thank you! And where/how can I get the response body ?

Comment: You can use `-o file.txt`

Comment: When I add this option, I get the following output in my terminal and nothing happen :
[1] 11619
azerty@vps197415:~/sq#   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

Comment: You need to put the URLs inside double quotes `"` (because they contain shell special characters), I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the redirects.

curl -L -d "server_name=www.starsquest.co.uk&uni=1&username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&x=0&y=0" --dump-header headers http://s2.starsquest.co.uk/?page=login

On you next request add the headers dumped to file from the previous request. Its should be something this.

curl -L --dump-header headers -H "Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 13:46:50 GMT" -H "Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Set-Cookie: __cfduid=daf5017ceaf3bd2369687ad910be2a3cf1468936009; expires=Wed, 19-Jul-17 13:46:49 GMT; path=/; domain=.starsquest.co.uk; HttpO$" -H "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u14" -H "Set-Cookie: proxy_check=1; expires=Tue, 26-Jul-2016 13:53:33 GMT" -H "Set-Cookie: starsquestsession_id=4f565c147ac949fa451020ae4c6b5ed0; path=/; domain=.starsquest.co.uk; httponly" -H "Set-Cookie: universe_var=2; expires=Wed, 19-Jul-2017 13:53:33 GMT" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0" -H "Expires: Mon, 18 Jul 2016 13:53:33 GMT" -H "Pragma: no-cache" -H "Vary: Accept-Encoding" -H "Server: cloudflare-nginx" -H "CF-RAY: 2c4e9f2d680b28d8-DXB" -X GET http://s2.starsquest.co.uk/game.php?page=showfleets&ajax=1

Please note that it is unethical/illegal to scrape some sites without their explicit permissions.

Answer (score 0):

use this just like @kryzk solution but add "-L"

curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt -L -d "server_name=www.starsquest.co.uk&uni=1&username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&x=0&y=0" --dump-header headers "http://s2.starsquest.co.uk/?page=login"

curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt -L -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET "http://s2.starsquest.co.uk/game.php?page=showfleets&ajax=1"